# Can a web page access resources cached by other web sites?

Tags: html, browser, browser-cache

Imagine an image with url https://example.com/image.jpg is accessed from page https://example.com/ . If another web page say, http://another.com/page shows https://example.com/image.jpg on the page, will the image cached by the browser be shown or new image will be requested from the server.

Comment: Yes, this is what caching is for.

Comment: I meant can a different domain access it?

Comment: Yes, of course! Cache is per browser, not per domain.

Comment: @WaisKamal Better add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The image will be cached by the browser, unless you specify otherwise in your browser's settings or the page serving the image specifies otherwise in its response headers. In fact, this is the main point of caching: to improve load times by avoiding repetitive requests to the same URL.